# Equivalent of Subset in Azure machine learning studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a dataset in azure machine learning (.csv), on the same dataset I have multiple models build, I want to subset data for each of the model based on a different column

Input:

```
ID col1 col2 col3
1  0    13   0
2  5    45   0
3  10   0    34
4  12   1    3
```

For the 1st model I want to retain all records where col1 not equal to None

```
ID col1 col2 col3
2  5    45   0
3  10   0    34
4  12   1    3
```

Similarly for model 2

```
ID col1 col2 col3
1  0    13   0
2  5    45   0
4  12   1    3
```

Hope it was clear

The equivalent in R would be

```
df[!df$col1 == "None",]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Execute R Script" module and just plug in your R code there.

```
df <- maml.mapInputPort(1)
df <- df[!df$col1 == "None",] 
maml.mapOutputPort("df");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect solution but we can use the module called "Split Data"

Input

```
ID col1 col2 col3
1  0    13   0
2  5    45   0
3  10   0    34
4  12   1    3
```

Expected Output

```
ID col1 col2 col3
2  5    45   None
3  10   None 34
4  12   1    3
```

Solution:

[image: Azure Machine Learning Screenshot]

Explanation:

I have used "MetaData Editor" to rename 'col1' to 'Labels'

The module "Split Data" is using Splitting mode as 'Regular Expression'

Under Regular Expression we are using the following condition

```
\"Label" ^0
```